# DevOps 2022 Server not connecting on VS 2012 and VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, azure-devops, tfs, devops

We are migrating our TFS server 2017 to DevOps Server 2022 but when we migrate our databases to the devops server our connection from visual studio 2012 and 2010 is not working while on Visual studio 2017 and 2019 the same connection is working fine on same machines. I need a solution so that we can access the DevOps Server on VS2012 and VS2010.

I tried the URL on Web and On VS 2017 and 2019 it is working fine on that the only problem I am getting is when connecting DevOps from VS 2010 and VS.
getting below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG1oJ.png)

Comment: I executed below command as well.
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, Azure DevOps Server 2022 has been configured to HTTPS.

The cause of the issue could be related to TLS1.2.

Refer to this blog: [Azure DevOps requires TLS 1.2 on all connections including Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/azure-devops-requires-tls-1-2-on-all-connections-including-visual-studio/)

> Azure DevOps will require TLS 1.2 for all HTTPS connections, including their web API and Git services.

> Visual Studio 2022, Visual Studio 2019, and the latest release of Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9 and beyond) already use TLS 1.2.

So you can successfully connect to Azure DevOps Server 2022 in vs2019 and vs2017.

When you use VS2010 and VS2012, you need to  set a set a machine-wide registry key to enable TLS 1.2 on all .NET applications including Visual Studio.

Here is the related PowerShell script:

```
If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SystemDefaultTlsVersions' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SystemDefaultTlsVersions' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Name 'Enabled' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Name 'DisabledByDefault' -Value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Name 'Enabled' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Name 'DisabledByDefault' -Value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

Write-Host 'TLS 1.2 has been enabled. You must restart the Windows Server for the changes to take affect.' -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [PowerShell script to enable TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/hybrid/connect/reference-connect-tls-enforcement#powershell-script-to-enable-tls-12)

Comment: Fixed with adding SchUseStrongCrypto.